# Directory Variable: .dirs-local.el with regexp

Tags: directory-local-variables

We can specify modes :

```
(c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
            (subdirs . nil)))
```

Or directories :

```
("src/imported"
       . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name . "ChangeLog.local")))))
```

Is there a way to specify a regexp matching files (or even directories) ? i.e:

```
(".*_test.go" . . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name . "ChangeLog.local")))))
```

Comment: Maybe consider filing an Emacs enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/62136/454

Answer (score 1):

The capabilities are documented at <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Directory Variables`

What you've asked for isn't supported; so no, you can't have regexps matching files or directories.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't simply do the regexp yourself in a .dir-locals assignment? eg just pasted from another exercise the assignment of fname could be based on a regexp matching the buffer-file-name

```
((nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (setq boilerplate (with-temp-buffer
                                        (insert-file-contents ".boilerplate")
                                        (buffer-string)))
                   (setq fname (buffer-file-name)) ; <--- do something with a regexp here to match the filename for type eg *.c etc.
                   )))))
```

Comment: Be careful using `setq` (as opposed to `setq-local`) in a dir-local `eval` form.  If the variable in question isn't buffer-local then you're setting its global value.