# .dir-locals for specific directory but not its children

Tags: dired, directory-local-variables, local-variables

How to set a directory local variable for a directory itself non-recursively? I don't want the variable set in `.dir-locals.el` affect the sub-directories.

---

Edited:

My use case is: I'd like to hide dot files under `~` by setting `dired-omit-files` since there are quite a lot of them in my home directory. But I do not want to hide dot files of any other subdirectory of `~`. Though I think I can set it using some `dired-mode-hook` by comparing `buffer-name` or `buffer-file-name`, I guessed there may be simpler solution by using directory local variables.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54974/454

Comment: You could test `(string= (expand-file-name dired-directory) (expand-file-name "~/"))` to see whether the current dired buffer is visiting your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

The [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) section of the emacs manual says:

> Here’s an example of a ‘.dir-locals.el’ file:
>
> ```
>  ((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
>           (fill-column . 80)
>           (mode . auto-fill)))
>   (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
>              (subdirs . nil)))
>   ("src/imported"
>    . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name
>                . "ChangeLog.local"))))))
> ```
>
> [... snip ...]  The special ‘subdirs’ element is
> not a variable, but a special keyword which indicates that the C mode
> settings are only to be applied in the current directory, not in any
> subdirectories.

so that should do the job, e.g.

```
((nil . ((dired-omit-files . t)
         (subdirs . nil))))
```

although for some reason when I test, it seems to be applying to all
directories, and don't have time to figure out why.  Perhaps you'll
have better luck!

Comment: That's a bug.  My initial take is that `dir-locals-collect-variables` is permanently deleting the `subdirs` element, and so it has no effect in any subsequent usage of that (cached) dir-locals spec.  Could you `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: I have no time right now, sorry. Maybe later.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You can set the variable in the directory-local variables, and the unset it in the child directory's variables. Or you can use file-local variables.

Comment: There so many subdirectories though...

Comment: @stackunderflow I suggest you edit the question to explain your use-case in detail.  What you're asking for isn't supported, but depending on what you're actually trying to achieve, there might be other convenient options.

Comment: Then consider using file-local variables instead. Or you could certainly consider extending Emacs so that it could support non-recursive directory-local variables.

Comment: @phils I've updated the question details.